# C# Backspace(\b) confusion

Tags: c#

Hi guys I tried to use backspace (\b) to an edit text and the output looks like this:`12⬜3⬜4⬜5⬜6⬜7⬜` .Can someone clarify me or suggest me a other method?

Comment: These kind of control codes go back to the days when programmers used teletypes to bang in their Fortran program.  It works in a console mode app, fuggedaboutit for a TextBox.  Just reassign the Text property.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about changing what's displayed on the console, you can use \r (carriage return) then overprint with whitespace, then re-print the line.

```
Console.Write("1");
Console.Write("\r  \r");
Console.Write("2");
```